# Got a Problem with Lag() in MySQL or Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, lag

I am trying to use the code below to get the 'overdue_days_last', which is one-record lagged order by 'statis_date'. I do not know what went wrong, but I got all the value of 'overdue_days_last' as 'Nan'. I wonder if it was caused by 'statis_date' as string, so I also tried using 'order by cast(statis_date as int)'. However, still all the record of 'overdue_days_last' were 'Nan'.
I checked with the raw data, and most of the 'overdue_days_last' value is supposed to be 0.
Can anyone help me out, please? Thank you!

```
    select substring(cast( date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(statis_date,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1) as string ),1,7) as Overdue_month,
       date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(statis_date,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1) as Overdue_date,
       trade_index, prod_code, certi_no, overdue_amount, 
       overdue_date as overdue_days, 
       lag(overdue_date) over (partition by trade_index, prod_code order by statis_date asc) as overdue_days_last
from FDM_SOR.T_SNUCS_T_BIZ_LOAN_D 
where overdue_date = 1
      and statis_date >= '20200331'
```

Comment: Did you get Nan or `NULL`?

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks for answering. I was new hired and ran the code on jupyter notebook at work. So I kinda pass the data to pandas dataframe and displayed it in pandas table format. Maybe the field value of ‘overdue_days_last’ should be null if displayed as SQL output? but it shows ‘nan’ in pandas dataframe? But neither value should be correct when I checked the raw data

Comment: Hive has both NaN and NULL.  They are different, and the difference is important here.

Comment: The overdue date should be a date, but your `where` statement is trying to filter it by an integer value. Is that correct?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you all for help. I found I made an obvious mistake but I did not realize before. I should not have filtered overdue_date to 1 in where clause. Otherwise, there was definitely no previous record of overdue_date. Instead, I should put the filter in the another ‘outer select’ from ‘this select’. 
And thank you Sayon for pointing out that overdue_date should be a date  other than an integer, but it was actually a naming error and the overdue_date here actually indicates days.